# How to implement odata producer for mysql or postgresql

Tags: java, mysql, postgresql, odata

I would like to learn how provide Odata service from either MySQL OR PostgreSQL using Java. I tried https://code.google.com/p/odata4j/. After running example app from odata4j, I don't see any Odata service. I tried couple of others. Unfortunately none of them successfully provide odata service from database.

I could only manage to run a console odata service without any actual database this http://www.odata.org/getting-started/basic-tutorial. This give me good understanding how odata service works in general.

I want to study or see some a an example that provides odata service from any database using Java. Please let me know. Thanks in advance!